# ordered result with case when multiple enteries satisfies condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, case

So with the case statement is there a way to get last entry which satisfies the When condition. 
Consider this

```
Case when hireDate > getDate() THEN hireDate END;

ID          HireDate
101             '07-28-2016'
101             '08-02-2016'
101             '08-04-2016'
```

Now with the above made up data, sql server will always output 07-28-2016, because its the first entry which satisfies the condition. Is there a way to get latest hire date with this case stmt, like 08-04-2016.

Comment: You should probably show your entire query, but if this is used in an `order by` clause, you can always add `desc` to the end.

Comment: _"sql server will always output 07-28-2016, because its the first entry which satisfies the condition"_ not with your query. You want to group by ID and select only one record with the latest `HireDate`?

Comment: @sgeddes. this case statement is used in a definition of a view so cant really put an order by .

Comment: Then show your entire query (or the relevant pieces) and let us know what's not working.  As is, we're left to guessing a bit...

Comment: ALTER VIEW  XYZ AS
SELECT ID,
  Case when hireDate > getDate() THEN hireDate END;
FROM abc

Comment: @ sgeddes above is the the exact lookalike of view definition. need 08-04-2016 as the hire date to be inserted into the view, the last condition that satisfies the CASE WHEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
alter view XYZ as 
select id, max(case when hireDate > getDate() then hireDate end) maxdate
from abc
group by id
```

Comment: I like this max solutuion

Answer (score 0):

> So with the case statement is there a way to get last entry which satisfies the When condition.

you can do some thing like ,getting max per group and querying against it.

```
;with cte 
as
(
select id,max(date) as hiredate
from yourtable
group by id
)
select 
id,
case when hiredate>getdate() then hiredate else  null end as 'hiredate'
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a CASE expression, use a subquery:

```
(SELECT MAX(hiredate) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE hiredate > GetDate() AND t2.PKColumn = MyTable.PKColumn)
```